# Наследование и коструктор

Tags: наследование, c++

Есть два класса

```
class cFunction
{
public:
    cFunction(double _a, double _b, double _c, double _x);
    virtual double getY();
protected:
    virtual double function();
    cArguments *args;
    double x, y;
};

class cFunction1 : public cFunction
{
public:
    cFunction1(double _a, double _b, double _c, double _x);
protected:
    double function();
};
```

конструктор для родителя выглядит как

```
cFunction::cFunction(double _a, double _b, double _c, double _x)
{
    args = new cArguments(_a,_b,_c);
    x = _x;
    y = function();
}
```

если для наследника  конструктор сделать как написано ниже, то метод function() вызывается родительский, несмотря на то, что он виртуальный

```
cFunction1::cFunction1(double _a, double _b, double _c, double _x) :
    cFunction(_a, _b, _c, _x)
{
}
```

если делать так

```
cFunction1::cFunction1(double _a, double _b, double _c, double _x)
{
    args = new cArguments(_a,_b,_c);
    x = _x;
    y = function();
}
```

то выходит ошибка

```
In constructor 'cFunction1::cFunction1(double, double, double, double)':
no matching function for call to 'cFunction::cFunction()'
```

как сделать, что бы конструктор наследника использовал собственный метод function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Базовый конструктор всегда вызывает функции базового класса.

По поводу второй ошибки. Вы не вызываете явно конструктор базового класса, и компилятор пытается вызвать конструктор по умолчанию, но его нет, поскольку Вы его перегрузили. Вот компилятор и ругается, что не может его найти.

Answer (score 2):

> если для наследника конструктор сделать как написано ниже, то метод function() вызывается родительский, несмотря на то, что он виртуальный

В конструкторе потомка виртуальная таблица перезаписывается самым последним действием, после инициализации всех полей предков, поэтому полиморфизм в конструкторе не работает.

> как сделать, что бы конструктор наследника использовал собственный метод function?

Вынести инициализацию за пределы конструктора.

**Update:** Саму `function`, конечно можно переопределить, вставив в цепочку наследования промежуточный класс, в котором и переопределить `function`, но это не решит проблему, т.к. первый предок, который использует `function`, является `cFunction`, т.е. класс, который порождает полиморфную цепочку `function` и в то же время, ее использующий.

Вот если их разделить (т.е. в одном классе определить `function`, а в другом - конструктор, ее использующий), тогда можно провернуть этот фокус. Но, в таком случае, все равно придется переопределять `function` в **промежуточном классе**, подставляя его в цепочку наследования перед `cFunction`.

Comment: См. обновление ответа.